# Method Swizzling and Inheritance

Tags: swift, method-swizzling

As I know, method swizzling with `method_exchangeImplementations(A, B)` function exchanges A method and B method in runtime.

If I get method with:

```
let A = class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, #selector(UIViewController.viewDidAppear))
```

it looks like Swift runtime replaces `viewDidAppear` method of `UIViewController` class -- superclass of `SomeViewController` inherits from.

But as I know, inheritance works on compile time, not in a runtime. In this case, how do they know, on runtime, that which superclass method (swizzled method or original method) should be called?

Here is simple example

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, #selector(UIViewController.viewDidAppear))
    let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, #selector(UIViewController.s_viewDidAppear))
    if let originalMethod, let swizzledMethod {
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }
    return true
}
```

UIViewController+S.swift

```
extension UIViewController {
    func s_viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("s_viewDidAppear")
    }
}
```

SViewController.swift

```
class SViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("SViewController.viewDidAppear")
    }
}
```

and this prints

```
s_viewDidAppear
SViewController.viewDidAppear
```

I expected only `SViewController.viewDidAppear` prints since inheritance works on compile time, and `viewDidAppear` method is swapped. And now I think runtime only swaps `viewDidAppear` of `UIViewController` because `s_viewDidAppear` is being printed. And this became conflict to me.

Comment: @Sweeper Ok, I'll add one

Comment: Your call to `super.viewDidAppear` ***is*** literally calling `UIViewController.viewDidAppear` - do you understand what `super` means?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes so in this case, actual call to `super.viewDidAppear` might be `s_viewDidAppear` because I swizzled method. But my thinking of how inheritance works was, like copying all `UIViewController.viewDidAppear` method to the location of `super.viewDidAppear` in compile time. But in that case, method swizzling would not work because swizzling works on runtime. So `super.viewDidAppear` is not determined in compile time.

Comment: "like copying all `UIViewController.viewDidAppear` method to the location of `super.viewDidAppear` in compile time" No, that's not how it works. There's no "copying".

Answer (score 1):

It's Objective-c's runtime, despite that it's implemented in Swift. Better to implement it with Objective-C to avoid confusions.

It's sending messages, instead of calling functions.
In compile time is determined, that super class is `UIViewController`, and you will sending message with selector `@selector(viewDidAppear)`.
Then when application executing, runtime will just receive message: call implementation of `[UIViewController class]` with `viewDidAppear` selectior.

You have exchanged implementations at app start, so new one will be called instead.
Btw you should have such implementation to call original code:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func s_viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        s_viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("s_viewDidAppear")
    }
}
```

Missing super's `viewDidAppear` can break something.

Comment: May be there is exist Swift's compilation parameter, to perform direct function calls instead of Objective-C's message sending and you can get desired behaviour with it.

Comment: Ah then would it be easy if I think inheritance creates instances of all the class that I inherited?